# converting ArrayList<Map<String, ArrayList<String>>> to xml and back to object

Tags: xstream

How to convert ArrayList>> to xml and back to object ? Pls give me reply soon.. So Urgent

Is there any way to do it in xstream or suggest me a manual way.

I am using Restful Webservice - java

How ll the xml look like?